# lateinit views in Android/Kotlin fragment

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin

All `lateinit` variables must be assigned in `onCreate` but in a `Fragment` the view does not exist until after `onCreateView` is called and this is called *after* `onCreate`.

Does it therefore follow that it is impossible to use `lateinit` variables for views in a `Fragment`.

It's a bit of a nuisance having to put `!!` everywhere. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: lateinit should be assigned before using not to be assigned in onCreate()

Comment: _"All lateinit variables must be assigned in onCreate"_ I'm not sure where you got that information. `lateinit` is a general kotlin feature, not something Android-specific. You do of course have to initialize the variables at some point before you attempt to use them.

Comment: @Michael that is the correct answer. It works if they are assigned in `onViewCreated`.

I'm new to Android development (14 years of C#) and find the documentation to be exceptionally poor.

Comment: If you're inflating layout from XML I suggest using kotlin synthetics or newly released android view binding to interact with your views. In some cases (like using a view pager) it's possible for fragments to undergo view destruction which clears all references to your views but it's not possible to do with `lateinit var`s.